# Custom Alert Dialog not resizing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I have created a Custom Alert Dialog by extending an `Activity` and inside the `onCreate()` method of this activity creating an `AlertDialog.Builder` object.

I'm loading my custom view but for some reason the dialog in the UI stays the same size whether I change something or not.

At first, I changed the `layout_width` to `fill_parent` but nothing. Then I put some absolute values like `300dp` but still nothing. This is the `sw360dp` layout of my app and it doesn't show well on this resolution that's why I want to edit it.

I'm also using the `Theme.Translucent` for this activity in order to make it seem like a dialog box.

Below is the layout for the dialog window and also a printscreen of my UI.As you can see the layout loads until create account button. The other text views don't fit.

Here's the screenshot

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/dialog_layout_root"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/light_gray">
         <Button
             android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/or_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textIsSelectable="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:textSize="12sp"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:layout_below="@id/facebook_login_button"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/sign_in_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textIsSelectable="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:textSize="16sp"
             android:textColor="@color/gray"
             android:layout_below="@id/or_text"/>
         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/login_email"
             android:layout_width="210dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:layout_below="@id/sign_in_text"
             android:hint="@string/email_login"
             android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/login_password"
             android:layout_width="210dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:layout_below="@id/login_email"
             android:hint="@string/pass_login"
             android:inputType="textPassword"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/case_sensitive_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textIsSelectable="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:textSize="14sp"
             android:textColor="@color/gray"
             android:layout_below="@id/login_password"/>
         <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/remember_login"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:layout_below="@id/case_sensitive_text"/>
         <Button
             android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@id/remember_login"
             android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/forget_password_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textIsSelectable="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:layout_below="@id/sign_in_button"/>
         <View
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_below="@id/forget_password_text"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/new_mav_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textIsSelectable="true"
             android:textSize="18sp"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:layout_below="@id/horizontal_line"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/create_account_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textIsSelectable="true"
             android:textSize="18sp"
             android:textColor="@color/gray"
             android:layout_below="@id/new_mav_text"/>
         <Button 
             android:id="@+id/create_account_button"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@id/create_account_text"
             android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/terms_conditions_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textIsSelectable="true"
             android:textSize="12sp"
             android:textColor="@color/gray"
             android:layout_below="@id/create_account_button"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/vertical_rule"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textIsSelectable="true"
             android:textSize="12sp"
             android:textColor="@color/gray"
             android:layout_below="@id/create_account_button"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@id/terms_conditions_text"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/privacy_policy_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textIsSelectable="true"
             android:textSize="12sp"
             android:textColor="@color/gray"
             android:layout_below="@id/create_account_button"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vertical_rule"/>             
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you change your parent Layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/dialog_layout_root"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

...

Try and write if it worked or not

*EDIT*

You are trying to make this dialog smaller?
So I think that problem is here:

```
<View
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_below="@id/forget_password_text"/>
```

And in other similar views. You set the width to be 360dp (it is the biggest width in your layout) so the parent will adapt to it..

Comment: tried with both fill_parent and wrap_content. I posted the xml layout with fill_parent because it was my last attempt.

Comment: good idea but I want to increase the Height of the dialog not the width. I tried it also but still nothing changed.